# UI-Bootstrap Modal not in Virtual Server Directory

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My website is located in this folder :

```
/var/www/deadpickle
```

Bower, the management I use for scripts, is located in this folder :

```
/var/www/bower_components
```

My website uses angularjs and ui-bootstrap (in the bower_components folder) to display a modal when the user clicks an item. My current issue is that when you click the item an error is received stating that it can not GET /localhost/deadpickle/template/modal/backdrop.html 404 (Not Found). I know the reason why, Its trying to use a URL to access the templates needed to create the modal and my bower_components are not accessible through a URL. My question, is there a way to get ui-bootstrap modal to not use a URL but to use a file path instead?

Here is the controller used to handle the modal:

```
app.controller('contentModalCtrlr', ['$scope','$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
$scope.opened = '';

$scope.open = function (template) {
  console.log(template,$modal);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: template,
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrlr',
        size: 'lg'
    });
};

$scope.$watch('opened', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue,oldValue);

    if (newValue == 'spellcards') {
        console.log('Open a Spell Card Modal!');
        $scope.open('spellcards.html');
    }
    else if (newValue == 'monstercards') {
  console.log('Open a Monster Card Modal!');
  $scope.open('monstercards.html');
}
}); 
}]);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to import backdrop.html, please?

Comment: I added what I use to call the modal. It looks like in the ui-bootstrap modal.js in the src directory they hard code the templateUrl for the backdrop.html and window.html